# Why gulp-livereload causes "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-livereload

In my [`gulpfile.js`](https://github.com/moroshko/github-explorer/blob/master/gulpfile.js) I set up [`express`](https://github.com/strongloop/express) to always return `index.html`.

```
var server = express();
server.use(livereload({ port: 35729 }));
server.use(express.static('./app'));
server.all('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: './app' });
});

server.listen(8000);
refresh.listen(35729);
```

All works fine the first time I navigate to `localhost:8000`. My Angular routes redirect to `http://localhost:8000/home`.

But, if then I refresh `http://localhost:8000/home`, I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Why is this happening?

<kbd>[DEMO HERE](https://github.com/moroshko/github-explorer)</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error caused by `angular route`. The scripts references in your `index.html` needs to be relative to the root. Otherwise they will not be found.

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script src="/home/home.js"></script>
<script src="/home/home-controller.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="/dashboard/dashboard-controller.js"></script>
```